# Calculating total cost per customer from a large data file

Tags: algorithm, spark-streaming, apache-storm, akka-stream, flume

I have task where I have to read a big file and process the data within. Every row in the file it look like this:

```
CustomerId   ItemId  Amount   Price
```

I then need to calculate the total cost for a customer, but first I need to work out the most expensive item purchased. I then having to substract the most expensive item from the total cost.

My idea is first I can make this table:

```
CustomerId  ItemId Total_Cost
```

Then I sort the table and find highest cost and store this in a variable.

Then I can make this table:

```
CustomerId  Total_Cost
```

Then I'll subtract the highest cost from each row.

I feel that this is a brute force approach, and I was wondering if there is a more clever and efficient way to do this. Also, I need advice on which library to use. I am confused as to which is best for this problem: Spark, Storm, Flume, or Akka-Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this faster by keeping track of the most expensive item purchased by each customer.

Lets asume your data is:

4, 34, 2, 500
4, 21, 1, 700
4, 63, 5, 300

On the first line, customer 4 purchases 2 items of 500. You do not add this yet to total cost because at this point this purchase is most expensive.
When line 2 comes, you compare this purchase against your most expensive, if more than replace most expensive and add previous most expensive to totalcost. If less, add to totalcost.